# Set Background of ToastNotification

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, toast

I want to know that how we can change the background color for the toast notification in Windows Metro (or Desktop) app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Foreground:
You can set "Foreground text" in you app manifest to dark or light.

Background:
This follows the "Background color" of the app manifest - and hence will be the same as the app's tile background.

For most of the apps I've worked on, it's enough to set the tile color according the UI spec - and then set the 'foreground text' to light or dark. You can surely override the light/dark themes if you want to too.

Comment: Hey andyhammar can I add padding in image of toastnotification?

Answer (score 4):

For desktop apps, the background color used on toast notifications (and Start screen tiles) is not configurable by the app itself. The color for the tiles is determined by the Start screen color theme chosen by the user (PC Settings -> Personalize -> Start screen), and the color of the background of toast notifications is always gray (when not in a high-contrast theme).

Comment: can we still now able to change its color ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it always use the color that is specified in your manifest file. So to change the color, you have to change the color of your whole application.

Comment: Hi Jan, so this is true for Metro app. but for desktop (WPF) app is there any way to change the background color of toast ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know enougth about metro wpf to know this. But mostly microsoft trys to keep a clear design in win8. So I think they don't allow custom toast-notifications because of design-guidelines.